# Python: Iterate API bytes string

Tags: python, loops, byte

So I'm using python for an assignment at school and I'm super new to python. I'm using an api to get some key phrases from a string.

The data is returned back to me using the .read() method. I'm having trouble getting values from the new byte string. It returns in a JSON-esque format:

```
b'{"keyValue":[{'KeyValue2': 'pairValue', 'keyValue3': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'etc']}], 'errors': []}'
```

What I need to do is get each string inside the keyValue3's set of values. I've tried setting a dict = to the byte string. That didn't work. Otherwise I could sort of iterate over the dict.

```
for data in myDict['keyValue']:
    myValue = data['keyValue3']
```

But even doing that doesn't quite work because I get the whole list of each string in keyValue3 instead of each individual string.

I also tried iterating over the byte string like you would a string and go char by char:

```
for char in myByteString:
    # algorithm to get desired chars goes here
```

After the first iteration through the loop, char = 123. Not sure why. But everything I've tried iteration-wise doesn't seem to be working. And it's probably because I don't know jack about python.

How do I pull just the strings out of the **keyValue3's** data?